# How To Stop App Data From Growing When Working With Photos

Tags: xamarin.forms

Posted this on the Xamarin forum and haven't gotten feedback yet.
Hoping someone here might be able to assist.

I'm writing an app (Xamarin.Forms) that allows the user to take photo's (using Xam.Plugin.Media) and then display them in a list view. 
I noticed the app data growing with each photo taken. And I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what the issue is.
I do not wish to save the photo on the device.
I've only tested this on android at the moment.

I wrote a sample app to simulate the issue. Steps taken as well as the XAML and view model code to follow.

1. Install app.
2. Go to Android / Settings / Apps / {AppName} / Storage
3. The app data is now approximately 10Mb and cache less than 1Mb.
4. Start the app, take a photo but DO NOT press 'OK' to confirm the photo taken.
5. Note that the app data has now increased with approximately the size of the photo in memory. (Let's use 5Mb, which brings the app data to 15Mb)
6. Press 'OK' to confirm the photo taken which then adds the photo to the list view.
7. Note that the app data has again increased with approximately the size of the photo in memory. (Again 5Mb, which brings the app data to 20Mb)
8. So with each photo taken the app data increases with approximately double the size of the photo taken, and as a result the app will end up using most of the device storage after a month of use.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, or if this is a result of poor coding. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Text="Take Photo" Command="{Binding TakePhotoCommand}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Photo List" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoList}" RowHeight="250">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="Fill" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

View Model:

```
public class CameraVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<MyPhoto> photoList {get;set;}
        public ObservableCollection<MyPhoto> PhotoList
        {
            get { return photoList; }
            set
            {
                if(value != photoList)
                {
                    photoList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PhotoList");
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand TakePhotoCommand { get; set; }
        public async void TakePhoto()
        {
            try
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                var mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });
                if (mediaFile == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                PhotoList.Add(new MyPhoto()
                {
                    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                    {
                        Stream stream = mediaFile.GetStream();
                        mediaFile.Dispose();
                        return stream;
                    })
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public CameraVM()
        {
            PhotoList = new ObservableCollection<MyPhoto>();

            TakePhotoCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                TakePhoto();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: May be Plugin.Media is saving a copy to temp folder or the folder you choose to save and then it save a another copy to album, and that is why it uses double size.

Comment: Xam.Plugin.Media is open source - you can easily debug the source to determine where/why this happens.  Possibly its a bug and you should file an issue in the repo.  However, I'd also note that the plugin allows you to control the size of the images it takes, so if you do not need a full res image then there are options to control the file size.

Comment: @KaranRami It might be the case that the plugin saves a copy of the photo somewhere (I'll do some research), but my code only works with the photo Stream, that's what's making this so strange. I checked my device and can't see any of the photos taken. I prefer this, and not to save the photo on the device.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I'll start debugging the source. I have played around with the image size properties, this does make a difference but over time the app data will still get very large. Also I'd prefer to keep the full resolution of the images. (The actual app uploads the photos to server and the reason I'm displaying them in a list is to allow users to delete them if needed.)

Comment: @KaranRami on further investigation I found that the plugin does save a hard copy to the device (even if I don't specify it) in the Android/data/{package name}/files/pictures directory. When I delete the file from this location after adding it to my list view data source, the image is no longer displaying. And I still need to figure out if and where the plugin might save the other copy.

Comment: files are saved on two different paths and you can get it by file.AlbumPath which is public path and file.Path which is private path as per documents on https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: try getting stream from one of this path instead from Mediafile.getstream(). and you can delete one of this copy, you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation I found that when setting the SaveMetaData and SaveToAlbum properties on the StoreCameraMediaOptions object to false, and then deleting the photo from the device after using it, the app data still increased, but not as much. When going through the device general memory usage, I noticed that the memory used for the default camera app was also quite large. After clearing the camera's memory, my app's data when back to a few kilobytes. I proceeded to take some more photos on my app, the app data grew (as expected), but after a couple of hours it was back to a few kilobytes. I suppose the device clears the memory for unused apps after a while.

Here is my working code. My app uploads the photo taken to a server and then displays this photo in a list view using the relevant URL. This is why i was able to delete the photo from the device afterwards. I suspect that if you try and display the photo taken using an ImageSource gathered from the photo taken it won't display after deleting the photo.

Only tested on android (Galaxy S8)

```
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    StoreCameraMediaOptions storeCameraMediaOptions = new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
    {
        SaveMetaData = false,
        SaveToAlbum = false
    };

    MediaFile mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(storeCameraMediaOptions);
    if (mediaFile != null)
    {
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ULHelper.ToByteArray(mediaFile.GetStream()));

        // Logic to upload photo to server using base64String

        if (File.Exists(mediaFile.Path))
        {
            File.Delete(mediaFile.Path);
        }

        mediaFile.Dispose();
    }
```